# How do you use scanf() or scanf_s() to ask the user for a string of characters?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, scanf

I will start out by saying that I am new to C and programming in general, and this is the first time I've asked a question about programming online.

I am using Visual Studio 2019.

I am trying to find a way to ask the user for a word, such as their name, and then have it printed out afterwards, like how I feel my following code -should- work.

I've looked around online and all of the examples I have found crash either when I try to run the code, or crash when I type in a word after it asks for a name.
I have tried using both scanf() and scanf_s().

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    char name[20];
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf_s("%s", name);
    printf("Your name is %s.", name);
    system("pause");
}
```

I expect the output to be "Your name is (name you typed in)."
But, I can't seem to make it work at all.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You use fgets, not scanf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it differently when using `scanf_s()` from the way you do it with `scanf()`.  You should use:

```
if (scanf_s("%19s", name, sizeof(name)) == 1)
{
    …got valid string…
}
else
{
    …error handling…
}
```

or thereabouts.  With `scanf()`, you'd omit the `sizeof(name)` argument.

The `"%19s"` format will skip leading white space and then start saving non-white space characters and stop reading at the first white space character, so typing `Jonathan Bailey` would only read `Jonathan` into `name`.  If you want any characters including spaces, then you need to change the format to `" %19[^\n]"` (where the space between the quote and the percent is very important) and make sure you read the residue of the line (including the newline) somehow.  The leading space in the format skips leading white space in the input, including newlines.  Do not add trailing white space to the format; that is a UI disaster.

Also, consider the merits of reading an entire line with `fgets()` and then processing the result — it avoids some complications.  You could use `sscanf()` to read the result — or custom parsing of your own choosing.  Use a big enough buffer:

```
char buffer[4096];

if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL)
{
    buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';  // Zap newline
    …process line…
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you.
I also found that with visual studio 2019, it doesn't like you using just scanf(), but if I add "#pragma warning(disable:4996)" (which I found online somewhere when searching for the error it gives me) it allows me to use scanf(), and it works just like you said it would.
Much appreciation.

Comment: You can also use `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` to disable the warnings about 'insecure' functions.  You can also look at the specification of [`scanf_s()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019) at the Microsoft Documentation site.